# 'vagrant ssh' not working with the vagrant-multi-putty plugin

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, putty, vagrant-windows

I am trying to run VirtualBox with Vagrant and the plugin vagrant-multi-putty. I am running Windows 10 and am following this [guide](https://github.com/CareerFoundry/rails-vm). All the plugins and steps seem to work fine until I get to the “vagrant ssh” step. I get this error:

[image]

I did some googling and the recommended solution is usually to set the path correctly to putty.exe. You can do that like so:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY
```

Even though the plugin seems to be installing right I can’t find the putty.exe file anywhere on my system. I tried downloading the binaries from [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and manually adding them to C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY. Then I set the path like the example above. However, I am still getting the same error when I run "vagrant ssh".

Comment: If the solution given by [@kmpm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109649/vagrant-ssh-not-working-with-the-vagrant-multi-putty-plugin#36327861) is not working, then please share your `Vagrantfile` to inspect the issue

Comment: That might have been useful 8 months ago when I asked this question. However, I had to find a different solution a long time ago. I am no longer even using the same system.

Comment: Alright @mrautoit,

Answer (score 1):

Made the same misstake myself at first.

According to the installation instructions for https://github.com/nickryand/vagrant-multi-putty you are supposed to use:

```
vagrant putty
```

instead of "vagrant ssh"